# Parentheses in siunitx table

Tags: tables, siunitx

I am trying to format a table using `siunitx` and LaTeX. Here is a MWE that resembles my data:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}[t]{l
                   r
                   r
                   S[round-mode = places, round-precision = 3, print-zero-integer=false, table-format = <0.3, table-space-text-post = {$^{***}$}]
                   r
                   r
                   S[round-mode = places, round-precision = 3, print-zero-integer=false, table-format = <0.3, table-space-text-post = {$^{***}$}]
                   r
                   r
                   S[round-mode = places, round-precision = 3, print-zero-integer=false, table-format = <0.3, table-space-text-post = {$^{***}$}]}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Variable A} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Variable B} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Variable C} \\
\cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){2-4} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){5-7} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){8-10}
\em{} & \em{B (SE)} & \em{$\beta$ (SE)} & \em{p} & \em{B (SE)} & \em{$\beta$ (SE)} & \em{p} & \em{B (SE)} & \em{$\beta$ (SE)} & \em{p}\\
\midrule
Intercept & 4.18 (17.53) & 0.00 (0.00) & <.001{$^{***}$} & 0.05 (0.14) & 0.00 (0.00) & .706 & 4.17 (0.91) & 0.00 (0.00) & <.001{$^{***}$}\\
Predictor A & -0.01 (0.13) & -0.01 (0.07) & .914 & 0.02 (0.03) & 0.05 (0.07) & .495 & -0.13 (0.22) & -0.04 (0.07) & .564\\
Predictor B & -0.13 (0.12) & -0.07 (0.06) & .285 & 0.07 (0.03) & 0.13 (0.06) & .038{$^{*}$} & -0.21 (0.21) & -0.06 (0.06) & .315\\
\midrule
Num.Obs. & 432 &  &  & 845 &  &  & 155 &  & \\
R2 & 0.20 &  &  & 0.11 &  &  & 0.54 &  & \\
R2 Adj. & 0.19 &  &  & 0.09 &  &  & 0.52 &  & \\
F & 5.28 &  &  & 4.47 &  &  & 8.42 &  & \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{10}{l}{\rule{0pt}{1em}{$^{*}$} p $<$ .05, {$^{**}$} p $<$ .01, {$^{***}$} p $<$ .001}\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

My goal is to align all values based on the decimal points, but I am struggling with the parentheses in the *B* and *\beta* columns. If possible, I would like to avoid splitting the values in parentheses into an additional column.

So far, I have tried `S[table-format=1.2 (1.2)]` but it did not work in the desired way (i.e., no space between parenthesis and preceding number, no decimal point).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `uncertainty-mode` to `full`, `siunitx` prints uncertainties as they are provided. In order to insert a gap between quantity and uncertainty, you can reformat `output-open-uncertainty`.

You should not resize tables. Rather try to decrease font size. IMO if you have to set a font lower than `\footnotesize`, it probably means your table needs to be redesigned. I also split your table into two parts in order to apply two slightly different formatting; `Num. Obs.` is an integer and should not be formatted; Hence, I enclosed all integers within two braces `{...}`.

In general, the whole table could be rearranged. The lower part seems like a separate table anyway. If you exclude it from the upper part, then you could move the groups `Variable X` to separate rows and repeated `Intercept`, `Predictor A`, ad n`Predictor B` for each group. That way, you could even fit the table horizontally. Currently, I had to use `sidewaystable` and render the table vertically to fit it in a page.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{rotating,graphicx}

\sisetup{
  round-mode = places,
  round-precision = 2,
  table-format = -1.3(1),
  uncertainty-mode = full,
  output-open-uncertainty = {\,(},
  retain-zero-uncertainty = false,
  print-zero-integer = true,
  table-column-width=1.9cm,
}


\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
  \footnotesize
  \centering
  \caption{Statistics}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{
    @{\;}
    p{2cm} *3{SSS[table-format=<0.3, table-space-text-post={$^{***}$}, round-precision=3, table-column-width=1.4cm]}
    @{\;}
    }
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Variable A} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Variable B} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Variable C} \\
    \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){2-4} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){5-7} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){8-10}
    \em{} & \em{B (SE)} & \em{$\beta$ (SE)} & \em{p} & \em{B (SE)} & \em{$\beta$ (SE)} & \em{p} & \em{B (SE)} & \em{$\beta$ (SE)} & \em{p} \\
    \midrule
    Intercept   &  {4.18\,(17.53)} &  0.00(0.00) & <.001{$^{***}$} & 0.05(0.14) & 0.00(0.00) & .706         &  4.17(0.91) &  0.00(0.00) & <.001{$^{***}$}\\
    Predictor A & -0.01(0.13)      & -0.01(0.07) & .914            & 0.02(0.03) & 0.05(0.07) & .495         & -0.13(0.22) & -0.04(0.07) & .564\\
    Predictor B & -0.13(0.12)      & -0.07(0.06) & .285            & 0.07(0.03) & 0.13(0.06) & .038{$^{*}$} & -0.21(0.21) & -0.06(0.06) & .315\\
    \midrule
  \end{tabular}
  \par\nointerlineskip
  \begin{tabular}{
        @{\;}
        p{2cm} *3{S[table-format=1.2]Sp{1.4cm}}
        @{\;}
        }
        Num.Obs. & {432}  & & & {845}  & & & {155}  & & \\
        R2       & 0.20 & & & 0.11 & & & 0.54 & & \\
        R2 Adj.  & 0.19 & & & 0.09 & & & 0.52 & & \\
        F        & 5.28 & & & 4.47 & & & 8.42 & & \\
        \bottomrule
        \multicolumn{10}{l}{\rule{0pt}{1em}{$^{*}$} p $<$ .05, {$^{**}$} p $<$ .01, {$^{***}$} p $<$ .001}\\
      \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

---

EDIT to render table horizontally.

First, consider adding the following snippet to preamble to see a frame denoting text boundaries

```latex
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.2pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{blue}}
```

I added code with two versions of the table.
If you have to resize it, beware the effect is degrading and is more visible the greater is a scale factor.
I would first make sure everything is minimised including font, column widths, spaces etc.
Then, I would apply `resizebox`.
Here's the first non-scaled version of the table exceeding left and right margins

[image]

The second scaled version fits the page.
Everything has been reduced to minimum so negative effects of `resizebox` are also reduced.

[image]

In the code, I have moved `tabular`s to saved boxes in order to measure their width.
This is not required if you decide on a scaled version because you will not need to apply negative space.
Just move everything back to the `table` environment.

```latex
% ... preamble remains the same
% ... add showframe to see text boundaries

\begin{document}
% Saved boxes
\sbox0{%
  \tiny
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{%
    p{1.4cm} *3{SSS[table-format=<0.3, table-space-text-post={$^{***}$}, round-precision=3, table-column-width=1.2cm]}
    }
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Variable A} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Variable B} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Variable C} \\
    \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){2-4} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){5-7} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){8-10}
    \em{} & \em{B (SE)} & \em{$\beta$ (SE)} & \em{p} & \em{B (SE)} & \em{$\beta$ (SE)} & \em{p} & \em{B (SE)} & \em{$\beta$ (SE)} & \em{p} \\
    \midrule
    Intercept   &  {4.18\,(17.53)} &  0.00(0.00) & <.001{$^{***}$} & 0.05(0.14) & 0.00(0.00) & .706         &  4.17(0.91) &  0.00(0.00) & <.001{$^{***}$}\\
    Predictor A & -0.01(0.13)      & -0.01(0.07) & .914            & 0.02(0.03) & 0.05(0.07) & .495         & -0.13(0.22) & -0.04(0.07) & .564\\
    Predictor B & -0.13(0.12)      & -0.07(0.06) & .285            & 0.07(0.03) & 0.13(0.06) & .038{$^{*}$} & -0.21(0.21) & -0.06(0.06) & .315\\
    \midrule
  \end{tabular}}%
\sbox2{%
  \tiny
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
  \begin{tabular}{
    p{1.4cm} *3{S[table-format=1.2]Sp{1.2cm}}
    }
    Num.Obs. & {432}  & & & {845}  & & & {155}  & & \\
    R2       & 0.20 & & & 0.11 & & & 0.54 & & \\
    R2 Adj.  & 0.19 & & & 0.09 & & & 0.52 & & \\
    F        & 5.28 & & & 4.47 & & & 8.42 & & \\
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{10}{l}{\rule{0pt}{1em}{$^{*}$} p $<$ .05, {$^{**}$} p $<$ .01, {$^{***}$} p $<$ .001}
  \end{tabular}}
\begin{table}[tbh]
  \caption{Statistics}
  %%% Table version exceeding margines
  % \hspace{0.5\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd0}\usebox0
  % \par\nointerlineskip
  % \hspace{0.5\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd2}\usebox2
  %%% Table version scaled to the page width
  \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\usebox0}%
  \par\nointerlineskip
  \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\usebox2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I totally agree with regard to the resizing of tables. However, I do have to squeeze the table into a vertical page format due to the requirements of the publisher. Is it possible to also apply your solution with the resize argument? If yes, which adjustments would I have to make?

Comment: @statleo I updated my answer. In general, `resizebox` has rather degrading effects as things are not scaled the same way. Make sure, you reduced components to minimum: fonts, columns sizes, spaces and then apply `resizebox`. Otherwise, you will get very ugly table.